# Copy file to app's own storage after downloading with download manager

Tags: android

I have a simple problem, on android 11.
Using download manager I can start and download a new database for my app.
When download is completed I get the response but when I try to copy the file to my app's database storage I get a permission error.
I can copy the file if I let the user choose it with built in filemanager.

Why do I not have permission to access the file if I initiated the download?

```
    public void downloadFromDropBoxUrl(String url) {
        //verfying if the downloadmanager is available first.
        if (isDownloadManagerAvailable(getApplication())) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
            recieverDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                    if (myDownloadReference == reference){
                        final TextView laai_boodskap = findViewById(R.id.laai_boodskap);
                        Uri downloadFileLocalUri = manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(reference);
                        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        query.setFilterById(reference);
                        Cursor cursor = manager.query(query);

                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

                      

                        if (downloadFileLocalUri != null) {
                            File mFile = new File(downloadFileLocalUri.getPath());
                        }
                        int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                        int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

                        switch (status) {
                            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                                Button LaaiDropBoxButton =(Button)  findViewById(R.id.dbLinkButton);
                                LaaiDropBoxButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                if (LaaiNuweData(downloadFileLocalUri.getPath())) {//savedFilePath)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Laaidatabasis.this, "WKR - DROPBOX Suksesvol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
                                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Kies die databasis"),
                                            PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);


                                };
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                                Toast.makeText(Laaidatabasis.this,"FAILED: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                                Toast.makeText(Laaidatabasis.this,"PAUSED: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                                Toast.makeText(Laaidatabasis.this,"PENDING! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                                Toast.makeText(Laaidatabasis.this,"RUNNING! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            registerReceiver(recieverDownloadComplete,intentFilter);
            final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
            request.setDescription("WinkerkReader Database Download");
            request.setTitle("WinkerkDB.sqlite");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DB_NAME);
            File dest = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "//" + DB_NAME);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Never use unreliable blobbing libraries. Rather create your own

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide errors so we can just guess the problem is in Provider.
Sometimes you need to use Uri as:

```
 Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                file);
```

provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
        name="your_directory"
        path="your_directory" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Error when opening the inputstream is : do not have permission to access the file

Answer (score 0):

> > Uri downloadFileLocalUri = manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(reference);

If you have a nice uri you should use it. And not like:

> > File mFile = new File(downloadFileLocalUri.getPath());

as getPath() will not deliver you a file system path.

Have a look at `mFile.getAbsolutePath()` to see an impossible path.

You could use mFile.exists() and mFile.canRead() before you try to use it.

To copy the file open an input stream on the uri itself. Then read the bytes of the file from the stream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(downloadFileLocalUri);
```

Comment: Uri looks like this:

Comment: Uri looks like this: "content://downloads/all_downloads/4248"
absolute file path: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/WinDB.sqlite"
I see the file actually exists in "/storage/sdcard0/Download/WinDB.sqlite"

Comment: error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/WinDB.sqlite: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Is that mFile.getAbsolutePath()? Hard to believe. And repeat: `You could use mFile.exists() and mFile.canRead() before you try to use it`. Well did you? Why dont you comment?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I am at GMT +2 only woke up now

mFile.exists() gives result TRUE
mFile.canRead() gives result FALSE   <- my problem?

Comment: Yes. You have an uri. Use it. How you constructed absolute path ftom uri you did not tell but it is wrong.

Comment: I think I solved my problem:
I moved my copy routine into the download manager reciever's "case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:"
Now  InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(downloadFileLocalUri); works.
My copy routine was outside the reciever, could this be why I get permission denied?

Comment: I dont know how you did that outside. And if you used the content resolver there too.